# Array from a SecureString list

Tags: powershell, csv, securestring

So I'm trying to decrypt a Csv that was `securestring` using a key and read it as an array, but when I decrypt it into plaintext using:

```
$unsec = $secure | convertfrom-securestring -asplaintext
```

it looks like several lines of this:

```
@{Num=123; RDM=abc}
@{Num=456; RDM=def}
```

What's the best way of decrypting the data into an array?

Thank you

Comment: `SecureString`'s are opaque instances of _string data_ - you can't store an array in a `SecureString`, only text. Serialize your arrays to JSON or another text-transmitted encoding scheme, then to securestring, and vice-versa

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.   It's just two columns in a CSV, numbering a couple hundred lines, it encrypts it and then decrypts it just fine, but I was hoping there was a quick way to remove the string identifiers so it's just a columns of num,rdm like the original format.

Comment: Seems like you forgot to convert your objects to CSV before turning it into a secure string

Comment: Yes that was it.   Thank you so much for the quick response and fix.   Works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to serialize the data before converting it to a `SecureString` otherwise you would end up with string representations of your objects when you convert it back to a plain `string`. You should use `ConvertTo-Csv` before `ConvertTo-SecureString`.

Using `Get-Process` as an example:

```bash
$csv = (Get-Process | Select-Object Name, Id | ConvertTo-Csv) -join [System.Environment]::NewLine
$encrypted = $csv | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString
```

Now if you want to decrypt the `$encrypted` string you can:

```bash
$encrypted | ConvertTo-SecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

You should also be aware of the [following limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-7.0#remarks):

> The maximum length of a `SecureString` instance is 65,536 characters.